# Building a NEO4J based web site

Tags: neo4j

Can I use NEO4J embedded in servlets and jsp to develop a web site where users will input relations between nodes and relationship properties so every user can see all the data or must I use NEO4J rest api .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of-course you can.
On the server start up, you can probably set-up the database. Then probably using dependency Injection (in Spring etc) or by using a static reference etc, refer to the db and execute functions. On termination, db can be shutdown.

In fact I would prefer it over the rest api (It has better performance and better grip).

Comment: So the best way to develop a NEO4J website would be by using servlets and jsp in a MVC pattern .

Comment: Yes. Also in the code, you can avoid `every user can avoid all the data` issue. Yes absolutely, you can completely do it. The rest api is awesome and saves time, but you have more control with direct java code itself

Comment: Actually I would prefer using cypher over pure REST as it is more expressive and would handle complete operations on the call level.